# How to retrieve all parents with children having many-to-one relationship defined in children entity in JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Entity **A**,

```
@Entity
class A {
    ...
    private String propertyA;
    private String propertyA1;
}
```

Entity **B**

```
@Entity
class B {
    ...
    @ManyToOne()
    private A a;
    private String propertyB;
    private String propertyB1;
}
```

Repositories

```
@Repository
interface A extends CrudRepository<A, Long> {
}
```

```
@Repository
interface B extends CrudRepository<B, Long> {
}
```

How can I retrieve all A(s) with their children. I want a JSON object similar like this.

```
[
  {
    "propertyA": "..",
    "propertyA1": "..",
    "B": [
      {
        "propertyB": "1B",
        "propertyB1": "1B1"
      },
      {
        "propertyB": "2B",
        "propertyB1": "2B1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "propertyA": "..",
    "propertyA1": "..",
    "B": [
      ...
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there any way to achieve this in JPA? I am newbie at Springboot and JPA.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "a") @JsonProperty("B") private Set<B> bs;` to `A`.

For this to work, you'll need to make sure the `bs` property is fetched while the persistence context is still open. You can do that by either (1) adding `fetch = EAGER` to `@OneToMany`, (2) using a query graph with the query to fetch `A`, or (3) enabling the `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` by setting `spring.jpa.open-in-view` to `true`.

(Depending on SB version, `spring.jpa.open-in-view` may or may not be enabled by default)